# How remove zero valued list from lists in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy

What is the efficient way of removing zero valued list from a lists of form:

```
[[u'xyz', 1, 2, 3, 4, 55, 6, 7], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [u'abc', 5, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

after removal of zero valued lists it should be of form :

```
[[u'xyz', 1, 2, 3, 4, 55, 6, 7], [u'abc', 5, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Tried couple of methods but those were completely removing the all zero of a list of lists.

Comment: Please post an example of your code and list out the methods you have tried.

Comment: There is no need for `u` before strings on Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach using `any` and `set`.

**Ex:**

```
data = [[u'xyz', 1, 2, 3, 4, 55, 6, 7], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [u'abc', 5, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
print([i for i in data if any(i)])
#Or
print([i for i in data if not all(j==0 for j in i)])
```

**Output:**

```
[['xyz', 1, 2, 3, 4, 55, 6, 7], ['abc', 5, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: What if a list has all 'abc's? I think he/she wants to remove list will all 0s only

Comment: why `any(set(i))` and not just `any(i)`?, or similarly, `all(j==0 for j in i)` instead of `all(j==0 for j in set(i))` why do you keep using `set` before passing it to `any`/`all`? The `set` serves no purpose, it doesn't avoid a pass over the sublist.

Comment: What if a list has all 'abc's? I think he/she wants to remove list will all 0s only ,
>> if it has all 'abc' it should print [all 'abc'], yes i want to remove list which contains all os.

Comment: instead of just printing can we remove those entries from list itself,
Ex. 
data = [[u'xyz', 1, 2, 3, 4, 55, 6, 7], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [u'abc', 5, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]] 
Output.
data = [['xyz', 1, 2, 3, 4, 55, 6, 7], ['abc', 5, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

Comment: @Skb just do `data = [i for i in data if any(i)]` then call `data`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution which I think should meet your requirements. It iterates over each list element in the main list and checks if all of its values are 0 by creating a temporary set within the function.

```
main_list  = [
    [u'xyz', 1, 2, 3, 4, 55, 6, 7],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [u'abc', 5, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]

def filter_zeroes(input_list):
    filtered_list = []
    for inner_list in main_list:
        create_set = set(inner_list)
        if len(create_set) == 1 and create_set.pop() == 0:
            continue
        filtered_list.append(inner_list)
    return filtered_list

result = filter_zeroes(main_list)
print(result)

# Output
# [['xyz', 1, 2, 3, 4, 55, 6, 7], ['abc', 5, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```